# How to get header info of this url using php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the header info of https://universalteambuild.com/ using both php get_headers and CURL but both get timed out.

This is the code I've tried.

```
<?
// try to get header using get_header
print_r(get_headers("https://universalteambuild.com/"));

// try to get header using CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://universalteambuild.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$a = curl_exec($ch); 
echo "$a";
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

To check if the url blocks CURL or header request, I went to https://onlinecurl.com/ and https://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php. Both were able to get the header info.

So I'm wondering if the issue is with the configuration of my server.

I would really appreciate if someone can run the script and see if you can get the header info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`get_headers()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) method to retrieve all the headers of an URL.

```
<?php
$url = "https://universalteambuild.com/";
$headers = get_headers($url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers)
?>
```

`get_headers` — Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to an HTTP request

Comment: I have tried it in my code above. I first tried using get_headers, then curl.

Comment: are you running in shared servers ?

Comment: No. It's a dedicated server.

Comment: Then what's the error you get when try to use get_headers method from php

Comment: PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://universalteambuild.com/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` on in your phpinfo()

Comment: Yes. allow_url_fopen is on.

Comment: The try to increase the timeout `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);`

Comment: Or else your outgoing ports might be blocked by firewall

Comment: I tried adding ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120); to the script. It still time out eventually.

Comment: Just curious. Have you tried running the script? It works for your server?

Answer (score 1):

```
For get_headers() : Check allow_url_fopen is On in php.ini
For curl: Check curl is properly installed and shows as 'enabled' in php.ini

Then restart the server after updating the php.ini
```

Comment: The server has no issue getting header info from other urls. Just this url is giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    ################### You can Try this code #######################

    $url = "https://universalteambuild.com/";

    // try to get header using get_header
    echo '<pre>';
    echo '++++++++++ get headers using  get_headers() method +++++++<br>';
    print_r(get_headers($url));

    echo '======================================================================<br>';


    // try to get header using CURL
    echo '++++++++++get headers using Curl+++++++<br>';


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);



// Then, after your curl_exec call:
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);//get header from curl response
    //$body = substr($response, $header_size);

    print_r($header);


    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```